# Connectionstring in web.config wont work. Not even with absolute path

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, connection-string

I've created a local database in Visual Studio with entity framework. But I can't get it to work. I get the "The underlying provider failed on Open."

I've tried with relative path to the database and absolute path but it wont work.

The project is MVC and the database is in an other solution in the project. (DataAccess > Logic < MVC)

The error I get when I run with absolute path. The error is the same with relative path:

`"An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file ~D:\\Visual Studio Projects\\Esport\\Esport.Domain\\Context\\Database\\esportDatabase.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share."}"`

My web.config in MVC:

```
  <connectionStrings>
<add name="esportDatabaseEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Context.Model.esportDatabaseModel.csdl|res://*/Context.Model.esportDatabaseModel.ssdl|res://*/Context.Model.esportDatabaseModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;attachdbfilename=~D:\Visual Studio Projects\Esport\Esport.Domain\Context\Database\esportDatabase.mdf;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

My App.Config in DataAccess layer:

```
    <connectionStrings>
  <add name="esportDatabaseEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Context.Model.esportDatabaseModel.csdl|res://*/Context.Model.esportDatabaseModel.ssdl|res://*/Context.Model.esportDatabaseModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\Context\Database\esportDatabase.mdf;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

EDIT: I moved the project to C: to get read and write and now it works with the absolute path. The problem is that I can't run it with absolute path. I need it to be relative. Any ideas how to do that? |DataDiretory| points to App_data and my database is not in app data..

EDIT2: When I run the relative path, |DataDiretory|esportDatabase.mdf I get this error:

`{"An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\\Esport\\Esport\\App_Data\\Context\\Database\\esportDatabase.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share."}`

But the database is not located there. Its located at: C:\Esport\Esport.Domain\Context\Database\esportDatabase.mdf.

Comment: are you using DB first migration in EF ?

Comment: Yes. Database first.

Comment: try removing the connectionstring from DataAccess layer?

Answer (score 0):

I have found that using code based configuration for EF is much easier to work with.

To gain complete control over what goes on with the connection string, you can create a special constructor for your DbContext derived classes that takes a connection string argument, and then use your constructor with a connection string every time you instantiate your DbContext classes.

The EF templates generate the DbContext derived classes as partial classes, which means you can add this constructor away from the auto-generated code.

It is fully explained here:
http://www.programmersranch.com/2013/11/c-ef-setting-connection-strings-at.html

FYI, you can manipulate DataDirectory like this, though you should be careful about how it could affect other parts of your application:

```
    string AppDomainDataDirectory 
    {
        get
        {
            object obj = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("DataDirectory");
            return obj != null ? obj.ToString() : "";
        }
        set
        {
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", value);
        }
    }
```